# Error while compiling PortAudio examples

Tags: c, portaudio

(I am on Ubuntu) I am trying to run the PortAudio examples, but getting many errors (mentioned below). I have placed the header file portaudio.h in the directory of the program. I have no idea about it. I think it is  linker error. Please help!

/tmp/cc5EbTlT.o: In function `main':
paex_record.c:(.text+0x37e): undefined reference to`Pa_Initialize'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x397): undefined reference to `Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x3de): undefined reference to`Pa_GetDeviceInfo'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x436): undefined reference to `Pa_OpenStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x45a): undefined reference to`Pa_StartStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x493): undefined reference to `Pa_Sleep'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to`Pa_IsStreamActive'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x4eb): undefined reference to `Pa_CloseStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x5fa): undefined reference to`Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x641): undefined reference to `Pa_GetDeviceInfo'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x6b2): undefined reference to`Pa_OpenStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x6e3): undefined reference to `Pa_StartStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x71c): undefined reference to`Pa_Sleep'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x728): undefined reference to `Pa_IsStreamActive'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x74e): undefined reference to`Pa_CloseStream'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x77d): undefined reference to `Pa_Terminate'
paex_record.c:(.text+0x7e5): undefined reference to`Pa_GetErrorText'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Yes, this is linker errors. How are you invoking the linker?

Comment: I tried to give some hints in an answer. If that does not help, please tell us how you are running the compiler/linker. I mean, from a shell (which command?) or from an IDE (which?) or ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are compiling using gcc and you have a single C file `foo.c`, the compiler command would be

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -lrt -lasound -ljack -lpthread -lportaudio
```

The `-l` parameters are there to link the required libraries to your program, e.g. `-lrt` will link `librt.a`. The order does matter.

I got the required libraries from here: http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html#comp_linux3. Don't know if they are correct. At least you need `-lportaudio`, obviously.

If the libraries are not found, you have to provide gcc a path, e.g.

```
gcc -L/usr/lib -o foo foo.c -lrt -lasound -ljack -lpthread -lportaudio
```

Regarding the header, you don't actually need to copy it into your program's directory. You'd rather include it as

```
#include <portaudio.h>
```

and add its directory to the include search path:

```
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -o foo foo.c -lrt -lasound -ljack -lpthread -lportaudio
```

Of course, all this is better done in a Makefile.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine earlier, but after reinstalling portaudio, whenever I run any program it gives this error -                           /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lportaudio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                                    Please help.

Comment: You have to find where `libportaudio.a` or `libportaudio.so` are located and tell the linker the path with `-L/path/to/lib/file/directory`. It should be something like `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`.