# Linking port audio library to C project

Tags: c, eclipse, portaudio

I'm currently trying to use the portaudio library to start build audio programs in C. The install I have is on ubuntu 16 and i've followed the steps for installing on linux. As far as I'm aware i've installed it correctly using everything on [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html) (including ALSA).

I've managed to get the `libportaudio.a` and `portaudio.h` file copied into the workspace file I'm using on Eclipse. I'm using a simple C program just to test that I have access to the library but even when I have both files in the workspace file the references are "undefined".

Are there any other ways I need to link the libraries to the project? Apologies if this is a simple task, I am relatively new to the matter.

For reference here is the program I'm testing this with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

int main(void){
  PaError err;
  err = Pa_Initialize();
  printf("Success!");
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while compiling PortAudio examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972796/error-while-compiling-portaudio-examples)

Comment: It's how you compile the program, aka how you link it. The command using gcc should look something like this `gcc -o foo foo.c -lrt -lasound -ljack -lpthread -lportaudio`

Comment: After you install libraries in system there is no need to copy anything into workspace. But you needs to add portaudio to the list of libraries used by project (`Project properties -> C/C++ build -> Settings -> Linker` page ).